# Basic properties of the Gabor-Fourier transform

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

studying for my PDE course I had to face the following object and its properties (I clarify that it was an evaluation that I already submitted), I wanted to know what you think, if it is correct or if you have a better idea

**Definition:**

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{C}$ a function in $S(\mathbb{R})$. We
> define the Gabor transform as \begin{equation*}
>          G[f](a,b) = \frac{1}{\pi^{1/4}}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(t)e^{-iat}e^{-(t-b)^{2}/2}dt\quad a,b\in\mathbb{R}. \end{equation*}
> Furthermore, for $h:\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{C}$ we define
> the inverse Gabor transformation by \begin{equation*}
>          G^{-1}[h](t) = \frac{1}{2\pi^{5/4}}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}
> > h(a,b)e^{iat}e^{-(t-b)^{2}/2}dadb. \end{equation*}

Next I will test some properties of this transform. Next I will test some properties of this transform, I would like to know what you think, if they are correct.

1. *Linear property:* Let $f,g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{C}$ and $\lambda,\mu\in\mathbb{R}$, then
   \begin{eqnarray*}
                   G[\lambda f + \mu g](a,b) 
                   &=&     \frac{1}{\pi^{1/4}}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} (\lambda f + \mu g)(t)e^{-iat}e^{-(t-b)^{2}/2}dt\\
                   &=&     \frac{1}{\pi^{1/4}}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} 
                   \lambda f(t)e^{-iat}e^{-(t-b)^{2}/2} + \mu g(t)e^{-iat}e^{-(t-b)^{2}/2}dt\\
                   &=&     \frac{\lambda}{\pi^{1/4}}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f
                    (t)e^{-iat}e^{-(t-b)^{2}/2}dt + \frac{\mu}{\pi^{1/4}}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} g(t)e^{-iat}e^{-(t-b)^{2}/2}dt\\
                    &=&    \lambda G[f](a,b) + \mu G[g](a,b).
   \end{eqnarray*}
2. *Shifting property:* Let $\beta\in\mathbb{R}$, and $f,g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{C}$ such that $g(t) = f(t-\beta)$, then
   \begin{eqnarray*}
                   G[g](a,b)
                   &=&     \frac{1}{\pi^{1/4}} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} g(t)e^{-iat}e^{-(t-b)^{2}/2}dt\\
                   &=&     \frac{1}{\pi^{1/4}} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(t-\beta)e^{-iat}e^{-(t-b)^{2}/2}dt\\
                   (\text{With }t-\beta = s)
                   &=&     \frac{1}{\pi^{1/4}} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(s)e^{-ia(s+\beta)}e^{-(s+\beta-b)^{2}/2}ds\\
                   &=&     \frac{1}{\pi^{1/4}} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(s)e^{-ias}e^{-ia\beta}e^{-(s-(b-\beta))^{2}/2}ds\\
                   &=&     \frac{e^{-ia\beta}}{\pi^{1/4}} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(s)e^{-ias}e^{-(s-(b-\beta))^{2}/2}ds\\
                   &=&     e^{-ia\beta}G[f](a,b-\beta),
   \end{eqnarray*}
   in short we have to
   \begin{equation}
   e^{-ia\beta}G[f](a,b-\beta) = G[g](a,b)\text{ when }g(t) = f(t-\beta).
   \end{equation}
3. *Modulation property:* Let $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$, let us consider $f,g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{C}$ such that $g(t) = f(t) e^{i \alpha t} $, then we calculate the transform of Gabor and we have to:
   \begin{eqnarray*}
                   G[g](a,b)
                   &=&     \frac{1}{\pi^{1/4}} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} g(t)e^{-iat}e^{-(t-b)^{2}/2}dt\\
                   &=&     \frac{1}{\pi^{1/4}} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(t)e^{i\alpha t}e^{-iat}e^{-(t-b)^{2}/2}dt\\
                   &=&     \frac{1}{\pi^{1/4}} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(t)e^{-i(a-\alpha)t}e^{-(t-b)^{2}/2}dt\\
                   &=&     G[f](a-\alpha,b).
   \end{eqnarray*}
   Therefore, we have seen that
   \begin{equation}
       G[f](a-\alpha,b) = G[g](a,b) \text{ when } g(t) = f(t)e^{i\alpha t}.
   \end{equation}
4. *Power integration property:* Note that we can write
   \begin{eqnarray*}
                   G[f](a,b) 
                   &=&     \frac{1}{\pi^{1/4}} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(t)e^{-iat}e^{-(t-b)^{2}/2}dt\\
                   &=&     \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{\pi^{1/4}}f(t)e^{-iat}e^{-(t-b)^{2}/2}dt\\
                   &=&     \text{FT}\left(\frac{1}{\pi^{1/4}}f(t)e^{-(t-b)^{2}/2}\right)(a),
               \end{eqnarray*}
   then we say that
   \begin{equation}
                   \label{Ecuacion01}
                   G[f](a,b) = \widehat{F_{b}[f]}(a),\text{ with }F_{b}[f](t) = \frac{1}{\pi^{1/4}}f(t)e^{-(t-b)^{2}/2}.
               \end{equation}
   Finally using the Plancherel theorem on $F_{b}$ it follows that
   \begin{eqnarray*}
                   \frac{1}{\pi^{1/2}}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} |f(t)|^{2} e^{-(t-b)^{2}}dt
                   &=& \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \left|\frac{1}{\pi^{1/4}}f(t)e^{-(t-b)^{2}/2}\right|^{2}dt\\ 
                   &=& \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} |F_{b}[f](t)|^{2}dt\\
                   &=&  \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} |\widehat{F_{b}[f]}(a)|^{2}da \\
                   &=& \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} |G[f](a,b)|^{2}da,
               \end{eqnarray*}
   therefore we conclude that
   \begin{equation*}
                   \frac{1}{\pi^{1/2}}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} |f(t)|^{2}e^{-(t-b)^{2}}dt = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} |G[f](a,b)|^{2}da.
               \end{equation*}
5. Energy sum property: Let $f,g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{C}$ be such that $f,g\in S(\mathbb{R})$, then note that
   \begin{eqnarray*}
                   \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(t)\overline{g(t)}dt
                   &=&     \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \left(f(t)e^{-(t-b)^{2}/2}\right)\overline{\left(g(t)e^{-(t-b)^{2}/2}\right)}dt\\
                   &=&     \sqrt{\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \text{FT}\left(f(t)e^{-(t-b)^{2}/2}\right)\overline{\text{FT}\left(g(t)e^{-(t-b)^{2}/2}\right)}dadb\\
                   &=&    \sqrt{\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} G[f](a,b)\overline{G[g](a,b)}dadb
               \end{eqnarray*}
6. *Recovery property:* Let $f\in S(\mathbb{R})$, note that:
   \begin{eqnarray*}
                   \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} G[f](a,b)e^{iat}da 
                   &=& \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \widehat{F_{b}[f]}(a)e^{iat}da \\ 
                   &=& 2\pi\left(\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \widehat{F_{b}[f]}(a)e^{iat}da\right) \\ 
                   &=& 2\pi F_{b}[f](t)\\ 
                   &=& 2\pi\left(\frac{1}{\pi^{1/4}}f(t)e^{-(t-b)^{2}/2}\right)\\ 
                   &=& 2\pi^{3/4}e^{-\frac{(t-b)^{2}}{2}}f(t).
               \end{eqnarray*}

The source of these properties is the following Wikipedia [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gabor_transform). The *Energy Decay Property* I did not manage to test, or at least not in a way that convinces me, if anyone has any ideas it is welcome

Comment: There is a problem in 5. did you mean to add $\int db$ in the first line. Otherwise *do you really need help*? It doesn't seem so. I don't even see any question in your question.